# How to change magento store location from www.mysite.com/magento2 to www.mysite.com?

Tags: magento2

I'm so sorry, I'm really new to Magento - I've tried my best to solve what is probably a very simple problem but I just can't find the solution. After installing magento2, the folder is located at mysite.com/magento2, and this is the URL that I can access my Magento store from. However, I want my store to be accessible from mysite.com. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone wondering, I managed to sort it out. I had Magento installed on a folder called Magento 2 on the server. I moved all of the files from this into the root of the server, then went on phpMyAdmin, selected my database, went into the `core_config_data` table and changed both `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to `http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

you can First update `mysite.com/magento2` to `mysite.com` in the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` URLs `core_config_data`.

clear `/var/cache` , `/var/generate`, `var/page_cache`

In your command prompt goto magento root:

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Set permission to /var and /pub  files and folder.